# How to create an 8-bit comparator with four 2-bit comparators?

Tags: comparator, fpga, xilinx

I am designing an 8-bit comparator in Xilinx ISE Project Navigator. My goal is to add four 2-bit comparators, as shown at the picture.  The input is a 16-bit literal, of which the first 8 bits are number A, the second are number B (SW(15:8) -> A; SW(7:0) -> B). There are two inputs BTN0 and BTN1, I use BTN0 to give the first comparator the EQ input value 1.
In ISim, the comparison works fine if the two numbers are equal, but gets weird when I try with two different numbers. I am working from several sources and I'm a beginner at all this, so there could be easily a bug/error I didn't think about.
http://25.media.tumblr.com/4e443e33d84b43e80e4f595b0044ab86/tumblr_mjd7vttpuc1r65yueo1_1280.png

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid the 2-bit comparator is not correct. For example, if A1 = 1, A0 = 0, B1 = 0, and B0 = 0, the output of the AND3B1 is 0, and the output of the AND4B1 will also be 0, so AG = 0.

Comment: You're right. The funny thing is, I tried to simulate only the 2-bit comparator in ISim, and I got different results than in the truth table I made. I'm gonna start over the whole thing from scratch, hopefully I'm gonna succeed this time. If I do, I'll post the results.

Comment: I've made another one, created a new 2-bit comparator, which is redundant but works fine. http://25.media.tumblr.com/9518377057f3a73349d0b9d0ccc0a549/tumblr_mjevfiIw001r65yueo1_1280.png